# AudiManager changing from Bluetooth to EAR_PIECE does not work

Tags: audio, bluetooth, phone-call, android-audiomanager, speaker

I have a button that should go from EARPIECE to SPEAKER to BLUETOOTH and so on.

This is my code:

```
 fun setSpeakerValue(value: SIPManager.AUDIO) {
        speaker = value
        when (value) {
            SIPManager.AUDIO.EAR_PIECE -> {
                Log.i("Speaker", "Speaker1 EARPIECE")
                binding.callItemIconSpeaker.setImageResource(R.drawable.speaker_off)
                if (SIPManager.isBluetoothConnected()) {
                    audioManager?.isBluetoothScoOn = false
                    audioManager?.stopBluetoothSco()
                }
                audioManager?.mode = AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL
                audioManager?.isSpeakerphoneOn = false
            }
            SIPManager.AUDIO.SPEAKER -> {
                Log.i("Speaker", "Speaker1 SPEAKER")
                binding.callItemIconSpeaker.setImageResource(R.drawable.speaker_on)
                if (SIPManager.isBluetoothConnected()) {
                    audioManager?.isBluetoothScoOn = false
                    audioManager?.stopBluetoothSco()
                }
                audioManager?.mode = AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION
                audioManager?.isSpeakerphoneOn = true
            }
            SIPManager.AUDIO.BLUETOOTH -> {
                Log.i("Speaker", "Speaker1 BLUETOOTH")
                binding.callItemIconSpeaker.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_data_bluetooth)
                audioManager?.mode = AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL
                audioManager?.isSpeakerphoneOn = false
                audioManager?.startBluetoothSco()
                audioManager?.isBluetoothScoOn = true
            }
        }
    }
```

But wheneven I ste to earpiece, I stopBluetoothSCO, I set isSpeakerOn to false, but after that, I start hearing in the blueooth instead of the earpiece of the phone. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: some options that come to my mind 1. move audioManager?.isBluetoothScoOn = false statement outside the if scope 2. do you have a seperate flag/boolean for AUDIO.EAR_PIECE 3. are you sure if BluetoothSCO is disconnected(can be confirmed from logs)?

Comment: 1.Doesn't help if I move it outside.
2. I don't have a boolean, it's just a ENUM I use with 3 states SIPManager.AUDIO.* 
3. I will check now, but when I press the button I do hear on the headset a beep that it was disconnected, and only after a couple of seconds it starts again

My guess is that the audioManager's mode has a channel and after it's configured for BLUETOOTH, when I try EAR_PIECE it will be the same? I'm not sure, tried using different modes for each type, but it's either 1 doesn't work properly or another one

Comment: There may issue with delay in setting up and tearing down Bluetooth connection.does it help adding a delay after Bluetooth connect and disconnect?

Comment: I will test after I finish with my current task and will let you know

Comment: I made it work using the example from my anwer. Also added a link to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work using the answer from here:
[How to switch audio output from Phone, Phone Speaker, earphones or Bluetooth device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47057889/how-to-switch-audio-output-from-phone-phone-speaker-earphones-or-bluetooth-dev)

```
 //For BT
        mAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
        mAudioManager.startBluetoothSco();
        mAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
    } else if(true) {
        //For phone ear piece
        mAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
        mAudioManager.stopBluetoothSco();
        mAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(false);
        mAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
    } else {
        //For phone speaker(loudspeaker)
        mAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
        mAudioManager.stopBluetoothSco();
        mAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(false);
        mAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
    }
```