# Need to populate list of connected Bluetooth headphones/buds and swtich audio output programmatically (Android)

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth

I am searching for long time but haven't found a proper solution yet. I have connected my phone with two different Bluetooth headphones and I can switch the audio output between them from the panel that slides from above in Android OS.

I need to populate the list of connected headphones (headphones/buds only) on my Android app, and also switch audio output to the target device when I click one of them, programmatically.

Can anyone help ? Thanks!

I tried using by retrieving Bluetooth profiles (such as A2dp, Headset) but couldn't find any solution to switch among connected devices.

I checked following one
[How to switch audio output from Phone, Phone Speaker, earphones or Bluetooth device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47057889/how-to-switch-audio-output-from-phone-phone-speaker-earphones-or-bluetooth-dev)
But I need to switch among devices when multiple headphones are connected (not just one).